# md-datepicker timezone issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm having a timezone issue with `md-datepicker`.

I have this element:

`HTML`:

```
<md-datepicker name="indate" md-placeholder="In Date" ng-model="fechain" ng-model-options="{ timezone: timezone }" md-min-date="fechain" md-max-date="fechain" required></md-datepicker>
```

And this is a piece of the controller related to the view:

```js
$scope.fechain = $scope.fechaminin = moment().toDate(); //Wed Jun 21 2017 21:10:59 GMT-0500 (-05)
$scope.timezone = moment().format('ZZ'); // "-0500"
```

But the datepicker shows june 22nd. I've been searching on Google but couldn't find any solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm not sure what exactly has gone wrong. Perhaps a version issue? Works for me though, check out my demo - https://jsbin.com/duwoxij/edit

Comment: This is a timezone issue. If you are in a timezone below 00:00. Then only this issue produces. I'm also facing the same issue, please let me know if anyone has any solution.